# Line coverage Unit Test in flutter with GoRouter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-test, gorouter

I am beginner in testing in flutter,
How to implement a test in this class
[image: Line coverage]

This is the code

```
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:moxify_app/src/features/features.dart';

final router = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: 'home',
      path: '/home',
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'login',
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Can you share your test case?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to came across this when doing unit tests. To cover that edge case, iterate through your routes and check if the route pagebuilder property is not null.

```
test(
    'check if routes are valid',
    () async {
      for (var route in goRoutes) {
        expect(route.name, isNotNull);
        expect(route.path, isNotNull);
        expect(route.pageBuilder, isNotNull);
      }
    },
  );
```

Comment: I will try this. Brb

Comment: Can you provide a full test @mike-g It looks like the test case is complete. What you meant by goRoutes here